# Use of FQDN, instead of IP, breaks Internet Explorer in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Even though I have configured Internet Explorer to be silent and invisible, navigating to my URL containing the FQDN will make IE popup on my screen, show the content of the URL (albeit the expected output) and popup an error in Excel. I do not get the same error or behaviour if I use the IP.

The error is:

```
Run-time error '-214702310 (800706be)':
Automation error
The remote procedure call failed
```

When I debug my script and hover above the highlighted line, I can see this error:

```
ie.readyState = <The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable>
ie.Busy= <The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable>
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub SleepEx Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long, Optional ByVal bAlertable As Boolean = True)

Sub test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer        
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    'url = "http://example.com/path/to/file"
    url = "http://ip.to.server/path/to/file"

    Debug.Print "Navigated to: " & url
    
    With ie
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = False
        .navigate url
    End With
     
    'loop until page is loaded
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
         SleepEx 50 'No busy waiting, short wait time
         DoEvents 'Need to receive events from IE application
    Loop  
End Sub
```

I know that I have a load-balancer facing these requests. I suspect that it may be the issue, but cannot imagine what it could be.

I have used Firefox to inspect the network traffic using both URLs. The only major difference seems to be an extra cookie and header related to `BIGipServer~v100` (confirming the load balancer).

**Update #1**

I did a `tracert` of the domain, which resolved to an IP (different that the IP mentioned earlier). If I use that IP, I have no issues either.

Comment: It could be that it's a local environment issue ..  Have you tried putting the domain into your `hosts` file and pointing it at the remote IP ?  Also is your protocol correct?  `http` vs `https` etc etc?

Comment: Yes, the protocol http is correct. My host file doesn't have any entries configured at the moment and I don't have the rights to edit this file either.